# Facebook Reveal Without PHP

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I found some code on here for NON-PHP Revealing HTML when the Like button is clicked however, not working for me. The code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<style type="text/css">
body {
width:520px;
margin:0; padding:0; border:0;
font-family: verdana;
background:url(repeat.png) repeat;
margin-bottom:10px;
}
p, h1 {width:450px; margin-left:50px; color:#FFF;}
p {font-size:11px;}

#container_notlike, #container_like {
display:none
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        FB.login(function (response) {
            if (response.session) {

            var user_id = response.session.uid;
            var page_id = "167544069999229"; 
            var fql_query = "SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE page_id = " + page_id +      "and uid=" + user_id;
            var the_query = FB.Data.query(fql_query);

            the_query.wait(function (rows) {

                if (rows.length == 1 && rows[0].uid == user_id) {
                    $("#container_like").show();

                    //here you could also do some ajax and get the content for a "liker" instead of simply showing a hidden div in the page.

                } else {
                    $("#container_notlike").show();
                    //and here you could get the content for a non liker in ajax...
                }
            });


        } else {
            // user is not logged in
        }
    });

});
</script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;
charset=iso-8859-1" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
FB.init({
    appId: '270349276366373',
    status: true,
    cookie: true,
    xfbml: true
});
</script>

<div id="container_notlike">
YOU DONT LIKE
</div>

<div id="container_like">
YOU LIKE
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have changed the APPID and PageID as necessary but not working and it keeps trying to bring up a pop up window.

It will eventually contain dynamic content in vb.net aspx file, so PHP isnt available to me.

Any ideas, can it be done server side through a SOAP or REST request?

Comment: Try the C# SDK, the dlls will be compatible with vb.net, however not many examples around showing vb syntax, so you'll have to convert it over yourself.

Answer (score 0):

you have to wait until the script is loaded and the FB va is init, try this flow...
if you have problem with login

```
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
    // fired when script is loaded
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
        appId      : '', // App ID
            channelUrl : '', // Channel File
        status     : true, // check login status
        cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });
        //do some stuff here (Login)

    };
    // Load the SDK Asynchronously
    (function(d){
        var js;
        var id = 'facebook-jssdk'
        var ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
        ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
    }(document));
</script>
```